# Updating Models with Approval requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

RoR 3

I have a user model with a few details, of which few of them are editable but requires approval.

I wanted to know what is the best practice to update a model as follows.

1. User modifies some data, data is sent for approval
2. User still sees the old data.
3. Moderator approves the changes.
4. User sees the new data

My current idea is to separate it as two models.

1. User Model
2. Profile Model

The user model contains the ID of the current profile, when the user updates his profile, he adds a new Profile model, and when the administrator approves of the same, the relevant profile model is linked to the user model. (The old one may be then destroyed).

The other ideas are

1. To have 2 attributes for every single attribute (but the edits will be minimal)
2. Since all of the editable entries are strings, and only use is for display, the actual model will contain a escaped JSON of both the current value, and the unapproved old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *current* idea will sure work. Something to think about though:

What happens when a user makes 2 or more changes without the previous one being already approved? He might change a different attribute or make yet another change to the previously changed one. The system will have to be able to merge these changes together because they would branch from a different base (different model).

Maybe a better solution would be to have a current profile and *waiting to be approved* profile (WTBA).

1. When there are no changes to be approved, the user sees the current profile.
2. The user makes a change, the system will create a WTBA profile.
3. The user sees the WTBA profile (but nobody else).
4. The user makes another change, the system will save the changes to the WTBA profile (not creating a new one).
5. A moderator approves the WTBA profile and at that point WTBA becomes the current and and we are back at #1.